# Confusion in barycentric coordinates

Tags: geometry

I've been reading Wong Yan Loi's notes on barycentric coordinates.

He mentions a lot the term parametrization of a line $l$.

As an example from the same source:

"There are two points
$P=((b-c)²:(c+a)²:(a+b)²)$

and

$Q=(-a(b-c)²:b(c+a)²:c(a+b)²)$

on a line $l_A$. We can parametrize $l_A$ as

$(x:y:z)=((-a+t)(b-c)²:(b+t)(c+a)²:(c+t)(a+b)²)$

where $a=BC, b=AC, c=AB$ the side lengths of the reference triangle $\triangle ABC$

My question is:

> What's a parametrization of a line? How can one do it?

Comment: Every point T on the line connecting points P and Q can be represented as T = tP + (1-t)Q.

Comment: "Parametric equations" are equations for, say, x, y, and z coordinates, depending on some other variable.  For example the coordinates of any point on a line in R^3 can be written x= at+b. y= ct+ d, z= et+ f.  Where a, b, c, d, e, f are constants and t is the parameter.

Comment: @blamocur Got it! Thank you! But what about this other example: "Let $D=(0:r:q)$, $l$$=[1:1:-1]$ .  A displacement vector perpendicular to line $l$, is $(q:p:-c²)$. Thus a parametric equation of the line through D that's perpendicular to $l$, is $(tq:r+tp:q-tc²)$. I can see that it's very reminiscent of the equation you wrote, but I can't see how to get it.

Comment: @mathlover  If you transform the first form to T = Q + t (P-Q) then you get a parametrization  of a line going through point Q along vector (P-Q).

Comment: @blamocur Got it! Thank you again!